# How do you programmatically remove a binding from a Polymer 1.x component in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, binding, polymer

If I have a component that has a binding:

```
<paper-input id="myField" value="{{someVar}}"></paper-input>
```

How do I remove that binding programmatically using JavaScript in Polymer >1.0?

Comment: There's really no good way to add or remove bindings at runtime. They're set up when the element's registered.

What are you trying to do that requires removing the binding?

Comment: Emulate the Material Design Date Picker ( https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/pickers.html#pickers-date-pickers ) where changing months animates calendars into view. The only strategy I could think of was to use 2 calendars, and toggle one to "ignore" the currentDate binding change via a computed binding. It works, but is a ton of code. If I could just turn off the binding, this would be a lot easier.